# How to hide some points inside my line graphic in React ChartJS 2?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

I would like to hide or change the color of point when its own value is 0.

Previous version of ChartJS you had the access to these point elements through the code below:

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data);
for (var i = 1; i <= data.datasets[0].data.length - 1; i++) 
   if (data.datasets[0].data[i - 1] === data.datasets[0].data[i])
      myChart.datasets[0].points[i].display = false;
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3tok57dL/

I'm using chart.js 2.7.0 and react-chartjs-2 2.6.2, and I can't find how to access these elements.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access some dataset properties applying to point (see http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html), for example `pointRadius` and `pointBackgroundColor`.

Check fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/79d1bnf2/

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

var data = {
  labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "My Second dataset",
    fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 19, 86, 27, 90, 28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
  }]
};
var options = {};
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: options
});

checkPoints = function(remove) {
  myChart.data.datasets[0].pointBackgroundColor = [];
  myChart.data.datasets[0].pointRadius = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= data.datasets[0].data.length - 1; i++) {
    if (data.datasets[0].data[i - 1] === data.datasets[0].data[i]) {
      if (remove) {
        myChart.data.datasets[0].pointRadius[i] = 0;
      }
      myChart.data.datasets[0].pointBackgroundColor[i] = 'red';
    } else {
      myChart.data.datasets[0].pointBackgroundColor[i] = 'blue';
    }
  }
  myChart.update();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="checkPoints()">check points</button>
<button onclick="checkPoints(1)">check points and remove</button>

<canvas id="myChart" height="300" width="800"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My code is having some weird behave! hehe 
The point hides when I put the mouse over it, but if I set the option "maintainAspectRadio", it works perfectly.

Comment: Which Chart.js version are you using?

Comment: Yes, it's working. I had to set the maintainAspectRatio to true to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at the API method [`getDatasetMeta`](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#getdatasetmetaindex).

> This returned data has all of the metadata that is used to construct the chart.

With this metadata you can set the `radius` of specific points to zero to hide them.

I reproduced your example with chart.js 2.7.1 below:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

var data = {
  labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "My Second dataset",
    fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 19, 86, 27, 90, 28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
  }]
};
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: data
});

var meta = myChart.getDatasetMeta(0);
for (var i = 1; i <= data.datasets[0].data.length - 1; i++) 
{
   if (data.datasets[0].data[i - 1] === data.datasets[0].data[i])
   {     
     meta.data[i]._model.radius = 0;
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="300" width="800"></canvas>
```

Comment: I think there is a bug with this version, because when you set the radius to 0, it works! But if you resize the window, the points return to initial state. Also, I have noticed that the last version, doesn't work when you have maintainAspectRatio set in the chart options.

Comment: And I have noticed as well that with the code from the another answer, it works with "maintainAspectRatio".

Comment: @ItaloBorges Resize causes chart.js to redraw the chart. Probably it would be better to set the radius to 0 in a [plugin](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html).

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look.